# Mysql seems to remove slashes from string

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running this exact query from PHP:

```
UPDATE commentedText SET title='§2.', content='<div class=\"pageParagraph\"><p>Test</p>\n</div>', last_changed='1430422172', image_banner_url='', active='', comments='[{"from":"0","to":"0","id":"1","CommentedText":"","comment":"New test with \"test\" :d"}]' WHERE id='5541d52beb2ea' AND appId='MyAppID' LIMIT 1
```

However when I read the row that was updated (either via PHP or MySQL Workbench), the slashes are gone. See for example

```
<div class=\"pageParagraph\"[..]
```

which is saved to the table as

```
 <div class="pageParagraph"[..]
```

How come the slashes disappear?

Comment: The slashes are used to escape characters for insertion.  To insert literal slashes you need to escape them \\ That's why you use prepared statements or at a minimum use the `escape_string` functions.

Comment: They disappear because you are not properly escaping your strings when executing your query or using prepared statements (recommended). See [this for PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [this for mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). If you're using `mysql_*` functions, be sure to switch to one of these others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper escaping when dealing with queries. Applying things like addslashes() are easily defeated.

Depending on your library, mysql_real_escape_string(), mysqli_real_escape_string(), or best yet, [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).

These methods of escaping will not modify the original data, so you don't have to worry about removing the escaping characters on render.

Comment: Great, I swapped to using mysqli_real_escape_string and now it works for double quotes. Single quotes however still gives me problems: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'single\\' quotes now?"}]' WHERE id='5541d52beb2ea' AND appId='MyApp' LIMIT 1' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

They are disappearing before they even get to MySQL -- PHP is seeing the backslash as an escape for the double quote.

```
"\""
```

creates a string `"`

To keep the backslash use

```
"\\\""
```

The first escapes the second, and the third escapes the quote.

Mysql also uses backslash escapes for strings.  So to use it in a query, you need to have it escaped yet again.

```
"\\\\\""
```

PHP's string will be `\\"`

Which in MySQL will create a string `\"`